# Union two select statements with different value in two columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, union

I have two select statements:

```
SELECT '1' AS ID , 'JOHN' AS SURNAME, NULL AS FIRSTNAME
SELECT '1' AS ID,  NULL AS SURNAME, 'BLOGGS' AS FIRSTNAME
```

How can I get this in the results in a way of combining two rows into one?

```
1 | JOHN | BLOGGS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `union all` and aggregation:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(SURNAME) as SURNAME, MAX(FIRSTNAME) as FIRSTNAME
FROM (SELECT '1' AS ID , 'JOHN' AS SURNAME, NULL AS FIRSTNAME
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '1' AS ID,  NULL AS SURNAME, 'BLOGGS' AS FIRSTNAME
     ) t
GROUP BY ID;
```